# Golang function default value

Tags: go

I'm trying to assign default value using struct, but how do I distinguish if it is zero value or the actual input value without using pointer?

```golang
type Options struct {
    a bool `default:"true"`
    // other options
}

func processOptions(options *Options) {
    if !options.a { // zero value - false
        options.a = true // what if the user actually input false?
    }
}

func test(options Options) {
    processOptions(&options)
    // ...
}
```

the pointer approach will be

```
type Options struct ...

func processOptions(options *Options) {
    if options.a == nil {
        aDefault := true
        options.a = &aDefault
    }
}

func test(options Options) ...

a := false
options := Options{&a}
test(options)
```

functional options mentioned by @maja takes advantages of variadic functions and struct type to make the 'constructor' initialize options safely regarding the types of each option.

```
type Options struct {
    a bool
    // other options
}

type Option func(*Options)

func WithA(a bool) Option {
    return func(options *Options) {
        options.a = a
    }
}

func NewOptions(opts ...Option) *Options {
    options := &Options{
        a: true // default value
    }

    for _, opt := range opts {
        opt(options)
    }
    return options
}

func test(options Options) {
    // ...
}

options := NewOptions(
    WithA(false),
)

test(*options)
```

Comment: You cannot do that with plain `bool` and no pointer. The only way to do what you want, without using a pointer, is to use a custom type that can represent those 3 different states (set "non-zero", set "zero", and unset). Something similar to how the `database/sql` package in the standard library deals with NULL values, e.g. https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#NullBool. Pointer or custom type are your only 2 options.

Comment: I think I'll go with pointer but it seems a bit clumsy because I have to init my Option with '&', and this is also the reason why I'm avoiding it.

Comment: Why do you even need to distinguish? Your argument is already a pointer: `*Option`. The user can already pass nil. The common approach is to store every "option" in its own struct-type and use a variadic argument in processOption() so that the caller can pass the options he wants. Or none, if the defaults are good enough.

Comment: @maja do you mean every single 'option' has its own struct type and use a variadic argument in both processOption() and test()? Because test() may accept more than one options, its just like a config.

Comment: @AARon Yes. See here for an example: https://www.sohamkamani.com/golang/options-pattern/

Answer (score 0):

In many cases there is no need to distinguish between a default value, or the value being explicitly set to zero.

Otherwise, you could use a pointer, or another field as a presence flag

```
type Option struct {
  a bool
  aProvided bool
}

func processOption(option *Option) {
    if !option.aProvided
        option.a = true
    }
}
```

This would require callers to initialize this extra field as well as a. To reiterate my above advice, it is often easier if you don't need to distinguish.

Comment: i'm trying to avoid using pointer in basic data types, but the presence flag approach require a lot of work if I have numbers of arguments

Comment: Please detail exactly what your question is and what your expected output is

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you already solve it your self using *string. But you want to avoid that ...

Why don't you make your all your options are default as it is. for example you have options `auto`=`true` and `repeat`=`false`. You can rename your options for default value like `auto` to `disableAuto`

```golang
type Option struct {
    Repeat bool // because repeat by default false
    DisableAuto bool // because auto by default true, this options purpose is to disabled auto
}
```

Updated:
or maybe you want functional options patterns, here my example https://play.golang.org/p/4DsSaQQkWg0

for more reference you can see here https://golang.cafe/blog/golang-functional-options-pattern.html

Comment: Not all zero values are good to be default e.g. a string defaults to "somevalue" will not work in this case

Comment: Ah... maybe you want functional options patterns like https://golang.cafe/blog/golang-functional-options-pattern.html